# Python equivalent of the PHP stdClass

Tags: php, python, stdclass

Coming from PHP, I love the pythonic syntax.
Is there a Python equivalent of the PHP stdClass?

Edit:
I want to point out I'm looking for a specific data type in Python to store data like the stdClass in PHP. So not in a dict, list, array, .. but in an object. Does there exist a specific data type in Python to store **only** data that behaves like an object?

Comment: Literally from the `stdclass` tag description: "... or object in Python"

Comment: What are you trying to do? There may be different idioms in Python for doing whatever that is.

Comment: Python is not as cool as PHP is. And python developers are less patient than PHP developers. If they don't like the fact that Python dose not have an `stdclass`, they will immediately vote to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```py
class StdClass:
    pass
```